# Execute condition based on which subset of 4 flags

Tags: java, algorithm

I want to find efficient algorithm based on which subset it is. New condition is to be executed for each subset.
For eg: I have 4 flags ABCD and each subset will have seperate condition. What is the most efficient algorithm to solve the following condition. It can be  made easily but I want to find the most efficient algorithm. Is there already an algorithm which solves this kind of problem?

```
A   B   C   D       
0   0   0   0   Subset 1    Execute Condition 1
0   0   0   1   Subset 2    Execute Condition 2
0   0   1   0   Subset 3    Execute Condition 3
0   0   1   1   Subset 4    Execute Condition 4
0   1   0   0   Subset 5    Execute Condition 5
0   1   0   1   Subset 6    Execute Condition 6
0   1   1   0   Subset 7    Execute Condition 7
0   1   1   1   Subset 8    Execute Condition 8
1   0   0   0   Subset 9    Execute Condition 9
1   0   0   1   Subset 10   Execute Condition 10
1   0   1   0   Subset 11   Execute Condition 11
1   0   1   1   Subset 12   Execute Condition 12
1   1   0   0   Subset 13   Execute Condition 13
1   1   0   1   Subset 14   Execute Condition 14
1   1   1   0   Subset 15   Execute Condition 15
1   1   1   1   Subset 16   Execute Condition 16
```

Comment: binary tree - O(log n).

Comment: For a small number of flags, concatenate them to form and integer and then use table lookup to retrieve a function pointer or an object and then execute a method on that object.

Comment: Why does this have the Mainframe tag?

Comment: It was by mistake. I have removed the mainframe tag.

Comment: Does the conditions directly depend on the flags ?

Answer (score 0):

[Bitmasking](https://www.topcoder.com/community/data-science/data-science-tutorials/a-bit-of-fun-fun-with-bits/) can be used to generate all subsets. There are four values. Therefore, you have 2^4 subsets. All you have to do is iterate this mask 2^4 times and mask it with each of the four values. In each iteration, the result of masking is a subset of the given values. Here's an idea:

```
allSubsets = {}
for mask in range(1<<4):
  subsets = []
  for i in range(0,3):
    val = mask & (1<<i)
    if(val)
      subsets.append(a[i])     # Individual subset. Here assume array a has 4 values. Can be just 1s and 0s as in your case.
  allSubsets[mask] = subset    #keep appending each generated subset

return allSubsets   # Do your operation by iterating on each of these subsets
```